# How to change the view of a map window in MapInfo to a new center coordinate?

Tags: mapbasic

How can I change the map view of a map window in MapInfo Professional to a new center coordinate? I need to change the viewed map in the MapInfo window via a predefined set of coordinates via MapBasic.

I tried to find it out through the MapBasic window but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Set Map statement.

```
Set CoordSys <some coordinate system specification>
Set Map 
    Window FrontWindow() 
    Center ( [some x coordinate], [some y coordinate] )
```

where [some coordinate system specification] shold be replaced with a representation of a coordinate system or reference to f.x a table:

```
Set CoordSys Table MYTABLE
```

And [some x coordinate], [some y coordinate] should be replaced with the coordinate of the new center point.

You will get a similar statement in the MapBasic window if you use *Map > Change View* to change the center of the map window.

Peter